# linq query to display records in order of year and month

Tags: linq

i am having following table:

salary table:
**salaryid,empid,basic,monthid,yearid,net salary**

year table:
**yearid,yearname**.(yearname is 2013,2014...)

month table:
**monthid,monthname**.(monthname is jan,feb...)

emp_master:
**empid,empname**

i am having following records in my gridview which i am fetching directly from table without any condition.

my table contain following records as shown below:

empname                 netsalary                month                year

abc                     4000                     dec                  2013

xyz                     4000                     dec                  2013

abc                     4000                     feb                 2014

xyz                     4000                     feb                 2014

abc                     5000                     mar                  2014

xyz                     5000                     mar                  2014

now i want to display records in order of month and year like first it should display records of highest month that is **march** and then **feb**.

i want output like this:

empname                 netsalary                month                year

abc                     5000                     mar                 2014

xyz                     5000                     mar                 2014

abc                     4000                     feb                  2014

xyz                     4000                     feb                  2014

abc                     4000                     dec                   2013

xyz                     4000                     dec                   2013

i have written query like this which is simply displaying records as it is in tables.

```
var data = (from s in context.Salary_Masters
           select new {name = s.emp_master.empname,
                       s.net_pay,
                       mnth=s.Month_Master.month_name,
                       year=s.Year_Master.year_name });
```

here{**name,mnth and year** as used as **anonomous type** in query are name of **datatextfield of my gridview**.}

can anyone edit my linq query to suit my needs ????

please please please help me.i am very much new to linq so i dont know how to write this query.

Comment: Try to use https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: can u provide me query for my above problem plzzzz???

Answer (score 1):

try this (not test make on the fly)

```
var data = (from s in context.Salary_Masters select new {name = s.emp_master.empname,s.net_pay,mnth=s.Month_Master.month_name,year=s.Year_Master.year_name }).orderby(z=> z.mnth,z.year);
```

Comment: when i am adding records of year 2015 then it is showing that record in middle not at the top

Comment: you need to invert z.mnth, z.year in z.year,z.mnth also remebers to use the keywords ascending, descending to choose in which order you need to show data

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have difficulty sorting chronologically if all you've got is month names to work with. If your month ids happen to be chronological ordered though (e.g. 1 = Jan, 2 = Feb etc) you could do:

```
var data = 
    from s in context.Salary_Masters
    orderby s.year_name, s.month_id
    select new {
        name = s.emp_master.empname,
        s.net_pay,
        mnth = s.Month_Master.month_name,
        year = s.Year_Master.year_name
    };
```

or you could add a numerical month_value column and sort by that instead.

Sorry, I've just noticed you actually want them in descending order so make that:

```
orderby s.year_name descending, s.month_id descending
```

Comment: bro my month id are chronologically order like jan=1,feb=2,marc=3 and so on

Comment: Then you can use this query to sort chronologically. Unlike your currently accepted answer, which sorts the months alphabetically.

Comment: but april records are coming after march when i am having records of year 2015 jan,year 2014 march,year 2014 april,2013 december

Comment: m so sorry.yeah your solution worked corrrectly.thank u so so much for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 var data = (from s in context.Salary_Masters
             orderby s.Month_Master.month_name,s.Year_Master.year_name
             select new {name = s.emp_master.empname,
                       s.net_pay,
                       monthName=s.Month_Master.month_name,
                       monthId = s.Month_Master.monthid,
                       year=s.Year_Master.year_name });
```

or you can try with lambda expression like this:

```
var list = context.Salary_Masters.Select(x=>new {x.emp_master.empname,
                                      x.net_pay,
                                      x.Month_Master.month_name,
                                      x.Month_Master.monthid
                                      x.Year_Master.year_name}).ToList();

list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year_Master.year_name).
ThenBy(x=>x.Month_Master.monthid).ToList();
```

Comment: you are welcome and happy it worled, coz i not tested it just thought it should be this way

Comment: bro r u master in writting linq query??

Comment: no  i am trying to master it,but not got success till..:)

Comment: you think like that its your kindness otherwise i am not so good.

Comment: bro i have written your query using lambda expression and when i am adding records of 2015 then it is showing me dat record in last

Comment: year_name is varchar or long or int?

Comment: i did orderbydescending so it should give you 2015 first, comment month ordering line and see what happens

Comment: try like this:
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year_Master.year_name);

Comment: bro in your query instead of monthname, monthid will come

Comment: you are talking about order by??